# Crear una tabla en sqlite usando una variable

Tags: python, sqlite

Quiero programar una función en python que cree tablas en una base de datos sqlite a partir de una variable.
Este código no funciona:

```
def creartabla(nombretabla):
    connectionObject  = sqlite3.connect("jez")
    cursorObject = connectionObject.cursor()
    createTable = "CREATE TABLE nombretabla (id int, nombre varchar(40))"              
    cursorObject.execute(createTable)
```

¿Cómo debería escribirlo?
Gracias.

Comment: Una forma: `createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + nombretabla + "(id int, nombre varchar(40))"`

Comment: cuando invoco la función con un parámetro me da error:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las maneras de pasar variables a una sentencia SQLite sería la siguiente:

```
def creartabla(nombretabla):
    connectionObject  = sqlite3.connect("jez")
    cursorObject = connectionObject.cursor()
    createTable = "CREATE TABLE '%s'(id int, nombre varchar(40))" % nombretabla             
    cursorObject.execute(createTable)
    connectionObject.commit()
```

Recuerda que justo al final de la sentencia debes realizar un `commit()` sino no se registrará en la Base de Datos.

Si necesitas mas información puedes visitar la página de la librería de [SQLite](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sqlite3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado usando %s tras create table y %nombretabla al final de la expresión.
Gracias por la ayuda.